# Check for partial match between 2 lists

Tags: python, list

I want to check if there is any similar elements between two lists.

For example:

```
ListA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
ListB = ['X', 'A', 'Y', 'Z']
```

I tried `any(ListB) in ListA` but that returns `False`

Is it possible to do something like this? I'm completely new to this language.

Comment: You are looking for sets, not lists.

Comment: `list(set(ListA) & set(ListB))`

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

[`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) needs an iterable of True and False values.

```
>>> ListA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> ListB = ['X', 'A', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> any(i in ListB for i in ListA)
True
```

Here you are testing if there is `any` value of `ListB` in `ListA`.

---

<sub>A better way as mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937937/check-for-partial-match-between-2-lists-in-python/33937970#comment55635200_33937937) is to use `set`s</sub>

```
>>> len(set(ListA) & set(ListB)) > 0
True
```

Comment: You need to check `len()` of set, or just use it in boolean context without any comparision. `bool(my_set>0)` yields `True` even for empty set.

Answer (score 1):

Use sets instead of lists:

```
>>> list_a = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
>>> list_b = {'X', 'A', 'Y', 'Z'}
>>> list_a.intersection(list_b)
{'A'}
```